# Sorting depending on the List identificator passed

Tags: java, list, sorting

Have a two methods, which sort Lists by one of the elements field value.

```
public static void sortItems(String sortingType, List<Item> items) {
    if (!sortingType.equals("NATURAL")) {
        items.sort(Comparator.comparing(Item::getLength));
    }
}

public static void sortPacks(String sortingType, List<Pack> listOfPacks) {
    if (!sortingType.equals("NATURAL")) {
        listOfPacks.sort(Comparator.comparing(Pack::getTotalLength));
    }
}
```

How can i combine them into one function, which will check passed List identifier and apply appropriate sorting?

Comment: Give them the same name then let Java's method overloading do the rest.

Comment: Not sure what exactly do you mean, could you provide a code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is only one difference between those two, so put that into the method parameters:

```
public static <T> void sort(String sortingType, List<T> list, Function<T, Integer> function) {
    if (!sortingType.equals("NATURAL")) {
        list.sort(Comparator.comparing(function));
    }
}
```

Then you can call that method with items:

```
sort("FOO", items, Item::getLength);
```

Or packs:

```
sort("FOO", packs, Pack::getTotalLength);
```